# Is it possible to capture a cache timeout in Django?

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, memcached

I would like to adopt the Django cache system to put an object in cache with let's say a 60 seconds timeout. Every time a cache hit happens such timeout is reset back to 60 seconds.

This should work fine but the problem is that I would also like to do something when the timeout occurs. Is that even possibile with cache?